# Database One to One Relationship Implementation

Tags: database

At the moment I haven't built any databases I'm still at the stage where I'm learning about planning a database using ER diagrams and lists of tables.

I understand what one to one relationships are, when to use them, when to avoid them, etc. What I don't understand is how are they implemented? Do they both have the same primary key? or do I simply put a foreign key in like a many to many relationship?

Comment: http://www.databaseprimer.com/relationship_1to1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One would normally implement this as a non-null foreign key on one of the tables that points to the primary key of the other and add a unique constraint on this foreign key.

You could also add check constraints to ensure that all the foreign keys in the table appear as primary keys in the other table and vice versa, though doing so makes it rather difficult to add and remove items from the two tables.

The other two options are:

- make a single table combining both entities. But this goes against the notion of an entity and the separation of data.
- Have a normal many-to-many implementation and enforce one-to-one via constraints as above.